# can i send answer to binary file with batch file

Tags: batch-file, sendkeys

I have Binary file and run that with a batch file with this code :

```
call "login.exe" site sample.com -user myusername
```

then binar file ("login.exe") waiting for insert password (ask password from standard input)

And i want to send password with echo or sendkey to that using from batch file

I'm using from this code

```
call run_binary.bat
timeout /t 1
%SendKeys% "password{ENTER}"
```

what can i do ? that is possible ?

Comment: i think you can send it back by running the script from login.exe...

Comment: @Proxytype I cant edit binary file ! so how ?

Comment: you can do a dirty trick and listen for all inputs, by attach to each open window, i can add example if it interesting...

Comment: @Proxytype Please add example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is a good point to start if you want to interact with open windows from another application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace keystroke
{
    public class handler
    {
        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(
        string lpClassName, 
        string lpWindowName
    );

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(
        int hWnd 
    );

    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);
    private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x80;
    private const int WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x40000;

    public const int GW_HWNDFIRST = 0;
    public const int GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
    public const int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    public const int GW_HWNDPREV = 3;
    public const int GW_OWNER = 4;
    public const int GW_CHILD = 5;

    public delegate int EnumWindowsProcDelegate(int hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
    public static extern void GetWindowText(int h, StringBuilder s, int nMaxCount);

    [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongA")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLongPtr(int hwnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetParent(int hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetWindow(int hwnd, int wCmd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int IsWindowVisible(int hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    public static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

}
}
```

you can find if the window that on focus, and active a keylogger but this is malicious...

Comment: What language is this? How is this code supposed to be used?

Comment: C# invoke win32 api functions

Comment: And how do you expect batch to run C#?