# How Can I Make A Keyboard Like On-Screen Keyboard Of Windows 7?

Tags: c#

I have a Form with a button . I want to press the Button in form instead of "W" key on keyboard and the "W" key become active and write in notepad "W".

that's very simply .

What's the Class or Method for this action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global Keyhook in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597890/global-keyhook-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you need to inject the data to other forms, i already show example how to do this here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084208/can-i-send-answer-to-binary-file-with-batch-file/31084326#31084326

Comment: "that's very simply ." Then why the need to ask others for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invoke "on screen keyboard" / avoid re-inventing the wheel where possible. the executable is osk.exe. In c#

```
Process.start("osk.exe")
```

this is equivalent to typing in osk.exe at commandprompt.

if you prefer not to use this for your application, on your form button click

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("W");
```

should do the job

Comment: Yes that solved my problem .  What about I want to Active Alt + W .                                               System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("ALT+W");    is it correct

Comment: :) / please see SendKeys.Send method reference in MSDN for special keys and sequence

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have the Ascii  cods of the Alt or Ctrl . Do you think the codes can work here .

Comment: I Read that but there wan't about combine codes like Ctrl + F .

Comment: sorry i join to this web for 2 days . i can't have chat

Comment: SendKeys.Send("{%}W") this should send Alt + W. Are you saying that this is not working?

Comment: I have just 1 reputation , not enough to chat

Comment: ok let me know if that worked over here, and we can fix it together if not

Comment: thank you so much you solved the big problem of me

Comment: this cod works  :  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("(%)w");

Comment: good / glad that I was useful. Good nite